# How to create custom Kotlin coroutine dispatcher worked on my ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the process of migration to Kotlin, the question arose. 
We already have some ThreadPools for different reasons.
How to execute coroutine on existed ThreadPool?


For exampe this code :

```
    suspend fun fetchMedia(): Flow<MediaItem> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {...} 
    }
```

How to replace Dispatchers.IO to my own ThreadPoolExecutor ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Executor ThreadPools calling `asCoroutineDispatcher()` on it, like this:

```
suspend fun fetchMedia(): Flow<MediaItem> {
    return withContext(myThreadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()) {...} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's ok, but how myThreadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher() looks like in java code?

Comment: When you call `asCoroutineDispatcher` on a ThreadPool, it returns a `ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher` object. You can use that data type in Java. Although I can't find any method to apply it directly on the ThreadPool, you could make a helper method in Kotlin that receives the ThreadPool and returns the`ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher` object  `fun getDispatcher(es: ExecutorService) = es.asCoroutineDispatcher()` and call it from Java.

Comment: In Java `executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()` looks like `ExecutorsKt.from(executor)`